# put javascript data in the html: inline script or data-attributes?

Tags: javascript, performance, browser

i need to send some data with the html page to the browser, which will be consumed by javascript (things like the user's details, etc.).
i see two ways to do it, and i wonder which one is better (blocks the browser less, performs better):

1.inline script in the html:

```
<script>var userData = {username:'joe',age:42,pet:'dog'}</script>`
```

2.data attribute in the html:

```
<div id="user-data" style="display:none" data-username="joe" data-age="42" data-pet="dog"></div>` and code in external javascript file: `function getUserData() {..this extracts the data from the div and caches it...}
```

i know that inline script-tags will block the browser, on the other hand they will be probably parsed much faster than when i will do it in javascript later.

Comment: Blocking only matters if you are doing serious processing (you aren't) or are making HTTP requests (the data is inline, so you aren't).

Comment: The data doesn't appear to be about the div element itself, so it certainly doesn't make sense for it to be there.

Comment: your two options are injection and ajax, i would recommend ajax.

Comment: @jbabey An ajax request would probably be noticeably slower, as it wouldn't initiate a(nother) HTTP request until the JS loads.

Comment: Ajax is a terrible idea in this context. It needs extra logic to copy with being asynchronous and adds an additional HTTP request to the mix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One school of thought is to consider using `<script type="application/json"></script>` for data you want to send along with your page, if you really don't want to use ajax. It's pretty easy to then write a script which grabs all json from the page as additional page data when the page loads. The benefits being you have deferred execution, you do not inject data directly into global scope and you are not generating JavaScript on the server side either.

Comment: this is nice. but it's important to escape the data correctly if the data contains user-submitted data. you basically have to replace '</' with '\u003c\u002f', otherwise the following json can cause problems: `{'t':'</script><script>alert(42);</script>'}`

Answer (score 0):

There's virtually no difference in performance, at least as far as your users are concerned. Using `<script>` tags would be much cleaner, so I'd say go with that.

The best way to add scripts (external or internal) is to put them at the bottom of the `body` tag. This will delay execution of scripts until the entire DOM is loaded, which not only boosts perceived performance, but, in most cases, you won't need `DOMContentLoaded` callbacks to get elements.

Comment: The code is just assigning data to a variable. There is no DOM manipulation involved, so no need to delay execution until the DOM is ready.

Comment: @Quentin we don't know if code elsewhere may do that, but regardless, it is good practice.

Comment: It is usually the right thing to do, but there are plenty of exceptions. Everything needs to be taken in context.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is directly related to a DOM element then I would use the second method ... however if the data is independent that the first method would be the way i would go....

There is no performance hit with either - there is no "blocking" of the browser.